What does $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} 1 - \zeta(n)^{-1}$ converge to?

Is there a closed form expression for
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (1 - \zeta(n)^{-1})$$

I know this sum converges, as
$$\color{Purple}{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\zeta(n) - 1)} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{n}} - 1 - \frac{1}{n} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n(n-1)} = 1$$
converges by comparison with $\zeta(2)$. And
$$\begin{align}
&\zeta(n) - 1 \geq 1-\zeta(n)^{-1}\\
&\zeta(n) + \zeta(n)^{-1} \geq 2\\
&\zeta(n) + \frac{1}{\zeta(n)} \geq 2
\end{align}$$
which is always true for any $\zeta(n)$, due to AM-GM inequality. Thus,
$$1 = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (\zeta(n) - 1) \geq \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (1 - \zeta(n)^{-1})$$
proving convergence.

Other evaluations of summations using the zeta function have been solved by using various representations of the zeta function. For example, consider the integral representation of $\zeta(n)$
$$\frac{1}{\Gamma(n)}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{e^x - 1}dx = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{e^x - 1}dx$$
Thus,
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (1 - \zeta(n)^{-1)} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(n)-1}{\zeta(n)} = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} [1 - \frac{(n-1)!}{\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{n-1}}{e^x - 1}dx}]$$
The reciprocal of the integral makes the sum tricky to evaluate. Using other representations of the zeta function results in the same problem. Are there any methods to get a closed form for this summation?

Using the Dirichlet series for the reciprocal zeta function (suggested by Gary), we have
$$\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (1 - \zeta(n)^{-1}) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (1 - \prod_{p \text{ prime}} (1 - p^{-n})) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (1 - \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(m)}{m^n}) = \sum_{n=2}^{\infty}  \sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(m)}{m^n}$$
$$=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(m)}{m(m-1)} = -\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}  \frac{\mu(m+1)}{m}$$
Computations suggest this value converges somewhere around $0.705211$.

Thanks.

Have you tried using the Dirichlet series for the reciprocal zeta function?

You need to use parenthesis when writing $\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} (1 - \zeta(n)^{-1})$

Now the first term with $m=1$ cancels and you can interchange the two summations.

Interchanging (then using partial fractions and $\zeta(1)=0$) yields $$\sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac{\mu(m)}{m(m-1)}=-\sum_{m=1}^\infty\frac{\mu(m+1)}{m}. $$

Is one less than Niven's constant, related to average largest power of a prime in prime decomposition of integers.  See also A033150 at OEIS and NivensConstant at Mathworld.  Not clear that there "should be" a closed form.

Thanks. This answer my question.
